# How to show the matrix equality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A=$ \begin{bmatrix} x & y\\ -y &  x\end{bmatrix} where $x,y\in \Bbb R$ and $x^2+y^2=1$.

Then show that for any $n\ge 1$;

$A^n=$

\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\ -\sin \theta &  \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}

where $x=\cos {\frac{\theta}{n}}$ and $y=\sin{\frac{\theta}{n}}$

**My try**:

The result holds for $n=1$.Assume that the result holds for $n=m$ To prove the result for $n=m+1$.

Now $A^{m+1}=A^m.A=$

\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta\\ -\sin \theta &  \cos \theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x & y\\ -y &  x\end{bmatrix}

where $x=\cos {\frac{\theta}{m}}$ and $y=\sin{\frac{\theta}{m}}$

But on multiplying I am not getting $A^{m+1}$.Please help me out .

Comment: What do you know about eigenvalues?  Have you seen Euler's formula, namely
$$
e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta?
$$

Comment: Also, you seem to be mixing your $n$'s and $m$'s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $x = \cos \phi$ and $y = \sin \phi$ for some fixed angle $\phi$.  By the inductive hypothesis, we have
$$
A^{n+1} = A A^n  = 
\pmatrix{\cos \phi & \sin \phi\\ -\sin \phi & \cos \phi} 
\pmatrix{\cos n\phi & \sin n\phi\\ -\sin n\phi & \cos n\phi}  =\\
\pmatrix{\cos \phi \cos n \phi - \sin \phi \sin n \phi & \cos \phi \sin n \phi + \sin \phi \cos n \phi\\
- \sin \phi \cos n \phi - \cos \phi \sin n \phi & - \sin \phi \sin n \phi + \cos \phi \cos n \phi}
$$
Use trigonometric identities to show that this is the same as the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{\cos[(n+1)\phi] & \sin [(n+1) \phi]\\
- \sin[(n+1) \phi] & \cos [(n+1) \phi]}
$$